# How to test shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I have made it accessible by declaring it in the .h file of the controller,
but I don't like changing visibility of methods for test purposes only.

**Is there any other way to call this method using Objective-C,**
ex. by temporarily from the testclass changing accessibility of the method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, as a reminder:
the method is declared in apple class UIViewController.h

```
// Override to allow rotation. Default returns YES only for UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;
```

so it's a public accessible method, and you don't need to declare it again in your subclass .h file

so, if you wanna call it directly for test, just do it (from any class that have a reference to an instance of your class):

```
BOOL rotating = [yourController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:1];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is override method, it get calls automatically, no need to call this method, or if still you want to try, then put debugger and test it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but please answer the question posed, or you may risk downvotes. It's the SO way...

Comment: `[self shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation];`

Comment: The question is about calling shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation from another class by dynamically changing the accessibility of the method. Question rephrase: Can you dynamically change the accessibility of a method in Objective-C ?

Comment: you can't change accessibility of method.

Comment: that method is already accessible, it's not a private method, you don't need to declare it. if your class is a UIViewController you can just call it

Comment: I want to call it from another class. I am testing the method.

Comment: then just do it, if you have a reference to the instance of your UIViewController ->  [yourController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:1];

Comment: @meronix make your comment a reply if you want points. Old Java habits, expecting all public methods after the dot on autocomplete fooled me this time.